# Laravel Query Relationship in 3 tables using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Help me again,

I have 3 tables

```
Product Table
id
product_name


Productquantity Table
id
prod_id -> product table id
price

Purchaserecord
id
prodquantityid -> productquantity table id
quantity
amount
```

How can I make to display the name of the product in my view? I have this on my Purchaserecord model

```
public function productquantity()
{
    return $this->belongsTO('App\Productquantity', 'prodquantityid', 'id');
}
```

and in my view

```
@foreach($dataPurchaseRecord as $Record)
<tr>
<td>{{$Record->productquantity->prod_id}}</td>
<td>{{$Record->quantity}}</td>
<td>{{$Record->price}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I just want to know how to display the product name instead of the productid {{$Record->productquantity->prod_id}}

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try this:

```
function viewPurchases(Request $request)
{
    //Perform your query, and end on ->get() to retreive iterable collection.
    $dataPurchaseRecord = Purchaserecord
                           ::with('productquantity')
                           ->where('id', '<', 10)
                           ->get();
    //load your view, and pass the collection to your view. 
    //compact('dataPurchaseRecord') basically results in a key value array like so: 
    //['dataPurchaseRecord' => $dataPurchaseRecord]
    return view('your_viewname', compact('dataPurchaseRecord'));
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I already have this on my controller however, I can only retrieve the product id not the name which is on the other related product table.

Comment: If you want to query the productquantity related to your Purchaserecord, you could replace the ::with('productquantity') by ::with(['productquantity' => function($query){$query->where('id', '<', 10); }])